# Integrate: $\int\frac{\cos x\sin Nx\sin 3Nx}{\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Integrate:
$$\int\frac{\cos x\sin Nx\sin 3Nx}{\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

We can rewrite the integral as:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\cos x\sin 2Nx}{\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\cos x\sin Nx}{\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x.$$

But how do I proceed further? Or could it be expressed as a special function?

Comment: This is the same question you asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705457/expressing-int-fracx2n-xnx-1-mathrmdx-as-a-special-function

Comment: There are at least two possible formulations for these antiderivatives. The problem is that you did not show any of your working. So, ...... ??

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I could only proceed till the last step as mentioned above. Actually, this is part of a bigger problem that I am working on. And this is what it has boiled down to so far. So, as I mentioned above, I don't know how to proceed after this.

Comment: At least, show some results for $N=1,2,3$

Comment: @AnishRay did the integral have bounds? If it did, we can take the fourier series transform and continue, but if unbounded, the closed form would go into hypergeometric series(verified with WA)